# Error occurs in passing image data to new view controller (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to pass an image ("imageData") from my current view controller into another view controller named "betaCompose". I was trying to unwrap it but it still gives me the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" error. Please advice. Thanks!

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: NSDictionary!) {
    let pickedImage:UIImage = info.objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as UIImage
    let scaledImage = self.scaleImageWith(pickedImage, and: CGSizeMake(320, 320))
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(scaledImage) 

    let bc = betaCompose()

    if let newImage = UIImage(data: imageData){
        bc.uploadedImage.image = newImage
    }

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    instantiateComposeView()
}
```

Comment: What's your `betaCompose()` constructor?

Comment: how is your `uploadedImage` added? As an IBOutlet? where is it initialised?

Comment: yes the uploadedImage was added as IBOutlet UIImageView. It was initialized at the very top.

Comment: the betaCompose() is the view controller to which I'm trying to pass the image.